# Devise user resource specific role Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan, rolify

I am working on a project management app in Ruby on Rails. I want to be able to assign users with different roles to each project (i.e admin, user). One obvious solution is to have two models running in devise, but that would mean, only users in the admin model could be admins on a project.

Is there a way to set it up so any user (i.e project creator) has admin rights to that project and other users can be invited to participate at read-only level?

Does anyone know a way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gone and used the [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) gem.

**Update:**
After working with Rolify for 6 months, I have learnt a lot more about the topic and am in the process of re-implementing a better solution using a mixture of [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) and [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan). I am working from [this tutorial](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial) provided by Rolify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'cancancan' gem to specify particular role permission.Once you refer that tutorial you get idea how it actually works.
You can user 'device_invitable' for send invitation to particular role user.

```
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan
https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable
```

If you want to use dynamic role permission than refer below link.

```
https://blog.joshsoftware.com/2012/10/23/dynamic-roles-and-permissions-using-cancan/
```

I hope this link will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. From what i can see, this is still attaching one role per user (correct me if I'm wrong). I need a user to have one role per project (e.g user1 is admin of project1 and contributor on project2). Thanks for your help so far!